# json fetch error handling then give it an alternative string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

Is it possible to give a default (alternative) JSON string if it cannot connect to the fetch url?

```
const Response3 = await fetch(`https://example.com/match/get?_=&id=${matchlist[2].id}`)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use fetch like a promise by adding `.then` to the end of fetch and reading the response.

```
const Response3 = await fetch(url).then((response) => {
  //Check the response coming back to see if it was successful
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return response.json(); //returns data returned from call
  } else {
    // if not successful, make your other call
    fetch(otherUrl).then(res2 => {
      if (res2.status === 200) {
        return response.json(); //if your second call was successful, return the data
      }
    })
  }
})
```

You can learn more about promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `try`/`catch` block

```js
let Response3;

try {
  Response3 = await fetch(`https://example.com/match/get?_=&id=${matchlist[2].id}`);
  if (!Response3.ok)
    throw new Error(Response3.statusText);
} catch (e) {
  Response3 = {
    prop: 'default json'
  }
}
// do something with the Response3 data here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
async function checkResponse(url) {
      const Response3 = await fetch(url);
      // thats mean pleas check the status of Response3 if it is equal to 404 (cannot connect to server)
      // otherwise put the same response (or the data you want like: Response3,players)
      let Response4 =
        Response3.status === 404 ? 'Cannot connect to the server' : Response3;
      /* 
      // or if you like if statment
      let Response4 = Response3;
      if (Response3.status === 404) {
        Response4 = 'Cannot connect to the server';
      }
    */
      console.log(Response4);
    }
    checkResponse();
```

If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer